# How can I configure AOP in ColdSpring 2.0?

Tags: coldfusion, aop, coldspring

I'd like to implement some before and after method advisors in Coldspring 2.0, and I'd like to use the [new schema](http://coldspring.sourceforge.net/ber/docs/xsd/beans/index.html) for AOP and the new autoproxying feature. Unfortunently, the Narwhal [documentation for AOP](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/coldspring/#AspectOrientedProgramming) is currently a cliffhanger. Can anyone give me an example of a Coldspring 2.0 configuration file that uses the AOP schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just finished off 1 more section in the AOP documentation, but in the mean time, here are a few examples to get the ball rolling.

This is an example of setting up around advice. It calls the method *timeMethod* on the object *timer*, that matches the pointcut of `execution(public * *(..))`, which translated to: *a method execution, that is public, that returns anything, that is named anything, and takes any arguments, of any types*. Essentially, it matches everything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.coldspringframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.coldspringframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.coldspringframework.org/schema/beans http://coldspringframework.org/schema/coldspring-beans-2.0.xsd 
    http://www.coldspringframework.org/schema/aop http://www.coldspringframework.org/schema/coldspring-aop-2.0.xsd"
    >

<!-- AOP configuration -->  
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="timer">
        <aop:around method="timeMethod"
            pointcut="execution(public * *(..))"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>


<bean name="timer" class="05_AOP.Timer" />
<bean name="longTime" class="05_AOP.LongTime" />

</beans>
```

The important piece to note, is that while Time.cfc is just a plain ol' CFC, for it to do the around advice, the method that is being used **has** to take a MethodInvocation as an argument, like so:

```
public any function timeMethod(required MethodInvocation invocation)
{
     ...
}
```

But there you go, there is an example of using AOP in CS2.

You can still use MethodInterceptors and the like as well, but you will be using `<aop:advisor>` rather than `<aop:aspect>`.

But overall, I'm working on the CS2 AOP documentation right now, so it should get filled out in the next day or so.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've been looking over examples from the Spring Framework, the AOP-2.0 schema, and the Coldspring 2.0 API documentation trying to figure this one out.  Looking forward to the new documentation.  Enjoy the reputation, I owed you a few points anyway.

Answer (score 1):

DOC RELEASED! http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/coldspring/